# Countdown Hours Minutes Seconds

Tags: javascript, counter

I'd like to create a countdown that count every hours, minutes, seconds remaining to 00:00:00 on July 13th at 12AM Miami time.

I'd like to addapt that code snippet and i struggle with calculs.
How shoud i adapt that code snippet for me to display hours, minutes, seconds instead of days, hours, minutes, seconds ?

How should i write the date for it to be 00:00:00 on July 13th at 12AM **Miami time** ?
What should i try next ?

Thanks.

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2022 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

-- WayneOS code snipped modification

````
// Format output-string
  var outputHours =  (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours);
  var outputMinutes = (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes);
  var outputSeconds = (seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  if (distance > 0)
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = outputHours;
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = outputMinutes;
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = outputSeconds;

  else
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

}, 1000);
```
````

Comment: you can use http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/examples.html

Comment: Be sure to read [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a JavaScript Date to a particular time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop to calculate the hours, minutes and seconds until `distance` is smaller than 1000. For it to end on Jul 13 12:00:00 use `new Date("Jul 13, 2021 12:00:00 GMT-4")` Here is an example.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jul 13, 2021 12:00:00 GMT-4").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
  var hours   = 0;
  var minutes = 0;
  var seconds = 0;
  while (true)
    if (distance >= (1000*60*60)) {
    
      hours++;
      distance -= (1000*60*60);
    
    } else
    if (distance >= (1000*60)) {
    
      minutes++;
      distance -= (1000*60);
    
    } else
    if (distance >= 1000) {
    
      seconds++;
      distance -= 1000;
    
    } else
      break;

  // Format output-string
  var hours   = (hours < 10 ? '0' + hours : hours);
      minutes = (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes);
      seconds = (seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  if (distance > 0) {
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = hours;
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
      document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
  } else
      document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";

}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you solution. It works perfectly. One question tho : is it possible to always display the counter as ***:**:** ? I'd like seconds from 0 to 9 to display 01 02 03... and not 1 2 3. Thanks !

Comment: @theovogg Of course it is possible. I changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much. The thing is, i'm trying to display hours, minutes and second in 3 different div with id #hours #minutes #seconds. I tried to modify your code, but i does not work (i pasted the code in my orinigal post). Thanks.

Comment: @theovogg I updated my answer again. Your code looked good to me. Maybe you find your error by looking at my solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have days, you can calculate the hours (days * 24 plus remaining hours). Here a little refactoring of your code. It uses `setTimeout` (more control and counting starts instantly) and a separate function to calculate the time units. [See also](http://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/mcyzuo4r).

Concerning the Miami time zone, you can create the date using timezone '[America/New_York](http://www.world-timedate.com/timezone/timezone.php?city_id=87)'.

```js
const getNextJuly13 = () => {
  const now = new Date();
  const miamiTime = new Date(`${
    +(now.getMonth() > 6 && now.getDate() >= 13) + now.getFullYear()}/07/13 00:00`)
    .toLocaleString('en', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'});
  return new Date( miamiTime );
};

countDown(getNextJuly13(), document.querySelector("#demo"));

function countDown(until, writeTo) {
  const distance = until - new Date();
  const diffs = dateDiffCalc(distance);
  const timeInfo4Demo = `\n\n=> Until ${
    until.toLocaleString()} (your TZ: ${
      Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone})\n${
        JSON.stringify(diffs, null, 2)}`;
  writeTo.textContent = `${diffs.totalHours}h ${
    diffs.minutes}m ${diffs.seconds}s${timeInfo4Demo}`;
  return distance >= 0 
   ? setTimeout(() => countDown(until, writeTo), 1000)
   : writeTo.textContent = "EXPIRED";
};

function dateDiffCalc(milliseconds) {
  const secs = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
  const mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  const hours = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  const days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

  return {
    days,
    hours: hours % 24,
    totalHours: (days * 24) + (hours % 24),
    minutes: mins % 60,
    seconds: secs % 60,
  };
}
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your refactoring. I checked, and can't understand something. Result is days 12, hours 2 but total hours is 578.

Comment: Thx @theovogg: forgot the modulus for remaining hours.